# PyBonjour error in Windows - Cannot load library libdns_sd.so.1

Tags: python, windows, ironpython, bonjour

When running PyBonjour under IronPython 2.6, I get an error which says:

```
OSError: IronPython.Runtime.Exception.OSException: cannot load library libdns_sd.so.1
```

This stems from the line:

```
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(_libdnssd)
```

Where _libdnssd is "libdns_sd.so.1" I have all of the Bonjour tools Apple distributes installed on the system.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: you need to check what installer in windows provide the file `libdns_sd.so.1`. In linux fedora, it is the package avahi-compat-libdns_sd that provide that file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been unable to figure that out; I can't even see if the installers I've used have put it on the system.

Comment: ok, I have no idea how windows work since you tag this question with windows. I can't assist you further, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that PyBonjour has a check similar to `sys.platform == 'win32'` to determine which DLL to load. That should probably be changed to `os.name == 'nt'` to work properly.

I haven't looked at PyBonjour to see if I'm right, though (if there's a way to do it without installing bzr I can take a look).